# Google Billing V3 null pointer exception

Tags: android, exception, billing

Basically I want to do a static test of Google Billing V3,before doing a real online test using the Beta Version thing. When I try to run my program,I get the following part of the exception...

```
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: connection is   
        null at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon
        (ContextImpl.java:1935)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1921)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService
        (ContextWrapper.java:529)
        at victory.walkto.paymenttestb.MainActivity.
        onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
```

The program I wrote is the following.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

IInAppBillingService mService;
ServiceConnection connection;
String inappid = "android.test.purchased"; //replace this with your in-app product id

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND");
    serviceIntent.setPackage("com.android.vending");
    bindService(serviceIntent,connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    connection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            mService = null;

        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            mService = IInAppBillingService.Stub.asInterface(service);
        }
    };

    Button purchaseBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.purchase);
    purchaseBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ArrayList skuList = new ArrayList();
            skuList.add(inappid);
            Bundle querySkus = new Bundle();
            querySkus.putStringArrayList("ITEM_ID_LIST", skuList);
            Bundle skuDetails;
            try {
                skuDetails = mService.getSkuDetails(3, getPackageName(),
                        "inapp", querySkus);

                int response = skuDetails.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE");
                if (response == 0) {

                    ArrayList<String> responseList = skuDetails
                            .getStringArrayList("DETAILS_LIST");

                    for (String thisResponse : responseList) {
                        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(thisResponse);
                        String sku = object.getString("productId");
                        String price = object.getString("price");
                        if (sku.equals(inappid)) {
                            System.out.println("price " + price);
                            Bundle buyIntentBundle = mService
                                    .getBuyIntent(3, getPackageName(), sku,
                                            "inapp",
                                            "bGoa+V7g/yqDXvKRqq+JTFn4uQZbPiQJo4pf9RzJ");
                            PendingIntent pendingIntent = buyIntentBundle
                                    .getParcelable("BUY_INTENT");
                            startIntentSenderForResult(
                                    pendingIntent.getIntentSender(), 1001,
                                    new Intent(), Integer.valueOf(0),
                                    Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0));
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1001) {
        String purchaseData = data.getStringExtra("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA");

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            try {
                JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(purchaseData);
                String sku = jo.getString(inappid);
                Toast.makeText(
                        MainActivity.this,
                        "You have bought the " + sku
                                + ". Excellent choice,adventurer!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                System.out.println("Failed to parse purchase data.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (connection != null) {
        unbindService(connection);
    }
 }
}
```

I also found out the google wallet can not be downloaded in your phone if you are using a Greek account!!! Paypal also stopped its operation with Greece due to the banking problems!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first create service connection and then bind the service.

```
// first this
connection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        mService = null;

    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        mService = IInAppBillingService.Stub.asInterface(service);
    }
};

// then this
bindService(serviceIntent,connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

Comment: Thanks man. The testing version is working. I would like to ask you something else. Should I use the same payload string for real online testing? Or should I generate a new one? Finally what should I put in the String inappid? My app's package name followed by productid(identifier of added product in developer console)? i.e.. victory.walkto.paymenttestb.productid

Comment: inappid and productId is the same string - id of your in-app product as defined in the development console. The first one (inappid) is used to query information about exactly this product id. If you have multiple products you will add multiple inappid's into the list. The second one (productId) is used to pick up a product with correct id from response. It only makes sense if you have multiple products. If there is only one product, response will contain details for that product only.